# Как упорядочить элементы таблицы SQLite в Android

Tags: sqlite, android

Допустим, у меня есть база данных SQLite с таблицей, в которой такие записи:

1. Оля
2. Дима
3. Катя
4. Денис
5. Олег

При удалении второго элемента, список становится таким:

1. Оля
2. Катя
3. Денис
4. Олег

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы колонка `id` подстраивалась под количество записей, чтобы не было пробелов в колонке `id`?

До варианта с тупым переписыванием я и сам додумаюсь, а есть ли какие-то средства у SQLite, которые помогут мне выполнить поставленную задачу?

Comment: Это будет дорогостоящая операция http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301817/sqlite-renumber-id-using-cycle

Comment: @sercxjo, в смысле, затратная по ресурсам?

Comment: Да, нужно создать вспомогательную таблицу, за тем пройти по всей старой таблице, время зависит от числа записей.

Comment: @sercxjo, сильно зависнет приложение, если записей 1000-2000? И почему вспомогательную? Просто всю колонку id переписать.

Comment: По ссылке такое решение через вспомогательную таблицу, можно и по-другому, просто в цикле пройти по всей таблице и переписать. Время я не мерил.